# Scraping data from Youtube with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
  var req = require('request');
  var cheerio = require('cheerio');
  req('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVRhrcoG6FOvHGKehYtvKHg/about', (err, response , body) => {
    if(!err) {
      let $ = cheerio.load(body);
      console.log($('style-scope.ytd-channel-about-metadata-renderer').html())
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
})
```

https://somon.is-inside.me/B49SiWJC.png

Hello, I'm trying to scrape the 'views' data in YouTube. But every time, it logs to console `null`.

There is a screenshot link, i'm trying to fetching data with class name but I couldn't get it to work. Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class selector character "."

try this `console.log($('.style-scope .ytd-channel-about-metadata-renderer').html())`

or this `console.log($('.ytd-channel-about-metadata-renderer').html())`

Comment: log the full html and check to see if the element you're looking for is even there